# Are recent pstricks changes to PStricks incompatible with tex4ht?

Tags: pstricks, tex4ht, make4ht

There have been a few updates to pstricks on ctan recently. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

   \begin{pspicture}(0,5)(2,2)
     \rput(1,1){Hi!}
   \end{pspicture}

   \begin{pspicture}(0,5)(2,2)
      \psline[linewidth=2pt]{->}(1.5,0)(0,0)
   \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

compiles fine with `latex` but when you run it through `make4ht`, which is a nice front-end to tex4ht, it crashes withe the first `pspicture` environment giving the error

> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
>   \endpspicture ->\pst@killglue \endgroup \egroup
>                                                   \ifdim \wd \pst@hbox =\z@ \e...

and the second environment giving

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   \endpspicture ...-\pst@dimb \pst@dimd =\pst@tempa
>                                                     \pst@dimd \advance \pst@di...

As the code is so simple, and it worked previously, I don't think it's anything that I am doing but would be very happy to be corrected.

Does anyone see a work around for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is fixed with the update from today and the second one seems to be a problem with `t4ht`. In `pstricks.4ht` the line 80 should be

```
\ifx\pst@tempa\@undefined\else
```

instead of current

```
\ifx\pst@tempa\@empty\else
```

However, this problem seems to be a long standing one. So I am wondering that it shouzld have worked in the past ...

Comment: thanks, I've updated the tex4ht sources

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply! I had already downloaded the pstricks updates before I posted and, at least for me, the updates do not fix the first issue BUT modifying `pstricks.4ht` as you suggest fixes *both* problems for me! The reason that I think this worked before the latest round of updates is that I have a lot of (more complicated) test files that worked before I updated pstricks earlier this week (and then again today), and these test files worked previously... In fact, with your fix in place, all of my "more complicated" tests past again. Thank you!

Comment: @michal.h21 Any idea when the next `tex4ht` release, that incorporates this fix, is likely to appear on ctan?

Comment: @Andrew it usually takes few days, maybe even tomorrow

Comment: @michal.h21 You're too efficient :)

Comment: @Andrew the update doesn't depend on me, it's on Karl Berry :)

Comment: @Andrew: It is simple to change the file by yourself. Run in a terminal `kpsewhich pstricks.4ht` and you'll see where the file is located.

Comment: @Herbert Hi Herbert I've already changed it on my computer (see comment above:). I'm asking more for others as I'm trying to push my package https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393309/feedback-on-new-package-for-creating-on-line-quizzes-from-latex to ctan...it's a little overdue since I announced this over a year ago.

Comment: A nice package, by the way ...